# display two DBMS_OUTPUT in a same line

Tags: sql, database, oracle, output

```
1. DECLARE
2. temp1 NUMBER :=digit;
3. BEGIN
4.  IF (digit<=0) THEN 
5.     Dbms_Output.Put_line( digit ||'! = ' || factorial);
6.  ELSE
7.      Dbms_Output.Put_line( digit ||'! = fact(' || digit||') = ');
8.  END IF;
9.   while (temp1 > 0)
10. loop    
11.     Dbms_Output.Put_line(temp1);
12.     IF ( temp1!=1) THEN  
13.     Dbms_Output.Put_line(' * ');
14.     ELSE Dbms_Output.Put_line(' ');
15.     END IF;
16.     temp1 := temp1 - 1; 
17.  end loop;
18. END;


I am trying to display line 13 in the same line of line 11 Is it possible
```

I have searched everywhere but no luck, every time i call dbms output it displays the out put in new line but I dont want that I want the output in same line. I want to try something similar to || pipe line so that i can display output in same line

Answer (score 1):

Use `dbms_output.put()` for the first part:

```
loop    
   Dbms_Output.Put(temp1);
   IF ( temp1!=1) THEN  
     Dbms_Output.Put_line(' * ');
   ELSE
     Dbms_Output.Put_line(' ');
   END IF;
```

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_OUTPUT.html#GUID-977C8AD1-D62B-4EFE-B24D-D0E6B262D9ED):

- PUT Procedure - Places a partial line in the buffer
- PUT_LINE Procedure - Places line in buffer

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zkrsJp0Q)